# Equivalent of Mathematica's ListDensityPlot[] function for Matlab

Tags: matlab, density-plot

Mathematica's ListDensityPlot[] can take a list of 3D coordinates, where the 3rd coordinate is a scalar, call it temperature or concentration etc. and return a density plot. The list would look something like

```
 temperature={{0,0,20},{0,1,25},...,{9,9,35}}
```

in Mathematica notation.

Mathematica automatically interpolates (I guess) over the values so it returns a continuous, smooth picture with a color scale to describe the scalar values on the 2D plane.

Is there anything equivalent to this in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html)?

Comment: @excaza contour seems to be the equivalent of ContourPlot[] in Mathematica, doesn't quite give a color function to every point on the grid, it shows all the points that solve an equation or inequality. 

So far it seems that pcolor is the only thing close to DensityPlot. But mathematica's ListDensityPlot returns a continuous result for lists as well, whereas as far as I can tell pcolor only returns pixelated blotches of color and I need to run my own interpolation to get a smooth result. Which is very unlikely to run faster and better than Mathematica's interpolation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Delaunay triangulation function of your planar points, then generate a surface over the triangulation.

It would look something like this:

```
Points=[xpoints, ypoints, zpoints];
tri=delaunay(Points(:,1), Points(:,2));
figure
trisurf(tri, Points(:,1), Points(:,2), Points(:,3))
shading interp
colormap jet
colorbar EastOutside
```